# multipass list failed: failed to determine IP address

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, multipass

When I run multipass list I am getting: list failed: failed to determine IP address.

sudo journalctl -u snap.lxd.daemon -n 300

```
lxd.daemon[3050]: time="2023-04-02T17:03:10-03:00" level=warning msg="Could not get VM state from agent" err="dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/multipass_amusing-labra>
lxd.daemon[3050]: time="2023-04-02T17:03:11-03:00" level=warning msg="Could not get VM state from agent" err="dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/multipass_amusing-labra>
lxd.daemon[3050]: time="2023-04-02T17:03:11-03:00" level=warning msg="Failed getting host interface state for MTU" device=eth0 driver=nic err="route ip+net: invalid network
```

sudo journalctl -au snap.multipass*

```
Timeout getting response for GET operation on unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/operations/d70c5119-9682-46a4-a5cd-29c5d418a029/wai>
Timeout getting response for GET operation on unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/operations/d70c5119-9682-46a4-a5cd-29c5d418a029/wai>
Caught an unhandled exception: Timeout getting response for GET operation on unix://multipass/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket@1.0/operations/d70c5119-
```

I am installing with a removable disk. It worked fine but after I unplug it sent this errors.

thank you

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127732/multipass-no-running-after-restart-service)? If yes, you should edit your original question with the new information instead of posting another question. If this supersedes your previous question you should answer or delete your previous question.

Comment: No it is running in different machines. In this case it worked fine after unplug the removable disk It didn't work any more.